# Sync Date and Time in Windows OS from python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

To avoid a time delay error with a (Binance) API I once in a while need to sync the Windows OS via the Data and Time settings.  I want to avoid doing this manually every day and was wondering if I can do this programmatically from python. I wasn't successful in finding how to do this

[image]

To run the exe file I am trying with a subprocess call but it does not get execute. Is this the right command and how do I make sure to run it as an admin?

```
sync_path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\'
sync_exe_name = 'w32tm.exe'
exe_to_run = sync_path + sync_exe_name
x = subprocess.run(exe_to_run, capture_output=True)
```

Comment: Call `w32tm.exe /resync` with administrative privileges

Comment: so what would the python command be to run this exe / resync command as an admin?

Comment: i have the same problem. As you have correctly stated, it is a windows (specifically windows 11) issue and not Binance, so i was initially searching for a windows solution (as this is desired) in place of a python solution...  but have not found one yet.

Answer (score -2):

```
os.path.realpath("C:\Windows\System32\w32tm.exe" )
```

Run this code

Comment: How will this help? Please read [answer].

Comment: it will synchronize your clock to the server time.

Comment: No it won't. That function [simply returns a cleaned up path](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath): "Return the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the operating system)". It doesn't do anything else. OP is already building this string and trying to execute the file it points to. The question asks whether this is the right command to run, and how to run it as Administrator, neither of which are addressed by this answer.

Comment: What is your work with Sync Time? Because this method really works when I use Binance Bot.